# Get all Attributes XML in python and Make it into a dictionary

Tags: python, xml, dom

XML:

```
<main>
    <item name="item1" image="a"></item>
    <item name="item2" image="b"></item>
    <item name="item3" image="c"></item>
    <item name="item4" image="d"></item>
</main>
```

Python:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('blah.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item')
for item in itemlist :
    #####I want to make a dictionary of each item
```

So I would get

```
{'name':'item1','image':'a'}
{'name':'item2','image':'b'}
{'name':'item3','image':'c'}
{'name':'item4','image':'d'}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code will create the dictionaries (no additional libraries are needed):

```
dicts = []
for item in itemlist:
    d = {}    
    for a in item.attributes.values():
        d[a.name] = a.value
    dicts.append(d)
print dicts
```

Answer (score 8):

I suggest to prefer the newer `xml.etree.ElementTree` standard module to the `xml.dom.minidom`. Try the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
for element in tree.getiterator('item'):
    print element.attrib
```

It prints

```
{'image': 'a', 'name': 'item1'}
{'image': 'b', 'name': 'item2'}
{'image': 'c', 'name': 'item3'}
{'image': 'd', 'name': 'item4'}
```

Here the `.getiterator('item')` traverses all elements of the tree and returns the elements named `item`. The `.attrib` of each element is a dictionary of the element attributes -- this is exactly what you want.

Actually, the elements behave as lists of subelements. With the above *attributes are items in the dictionary*, the ElemenTree fits much better with Python than the DOM approach.

Add the following code to the above sample:

```
print '----------------'
root = tree.getroot()
ET.dump(root)

print '----------------'
print root.tag
print root.attrib
for elem in root:
    print elem.tag, elem.attrib
```

It prints:

```
----------------
<main>
    <item image="a" name="item1" />
    <item image="b" name="item2" />
    <item image="c" name="item3" />
    <item image="d" name="item4" />
</main>
----------------
main
{}
item {'image': 'a', 'name': 'item1'}
item {'image': 'b', 'name': 'item2'}
item {'image': 'c', 'name': 'item3'}
item {'image': 'd', 'name': 'item4'}
```

Comment: `getiterator` seems to have been deprecated since version 3.2. What would you recommend these days?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen The answer was related to Python 2 older than 2.7. Python 3 introduced many interface changes, and the iteration through many structures was also unified (the API). This was later also backported to Python 2.7. As the doc says, you should use `.iter()` of the chosen element -- here of the `root` element that you get using `root = tree.getroot()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/534109-xml-to-python-data-structure/) Python recipe:

```
from xml2obj import xml2obj

data = xml2obj(s)['item']

# data content:
>>> [{image:u'a', name:u'item1'},
>>>  {image:u'b', name:u'item2'},
>>>  {image:u'c', name:u'item3'},
>>>  {image:u'd', name:u'item4'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

List/dictionary comprehension version of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11485560/8951763):

```
dicts = [{a.name: a.value for a in item.attributes.values()} for item in itemlist]
print dicts
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon actually trying this out, it errors out somewhere, but this should get you started if you don't want to use one of the other answers.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = BeautifulSoup('''
<main>
    <item name="item1" image="a"></item>
    <item name="item2" image="b"></item>
    <item name="item3" image="c"></item>
    <item name="item4" image="d"></item>
</main>
''')

item = xml.find_all('item')

count = 0
for snippet in item:
    eval('attribute' + str(count) = {'name':item[count]['name'],
                                     'image':item[count]['image']})
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This Python code will perform the task you want, but the output is not sorted as you indicated in your example output. Dictionaries have access by key but are not sorted.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
treexml = ElementTree.parse('test.xml')
for element in treexml.getiterator():
    dict_keys={}
    if element.keys():
        for name, value in element.items():
            dict_keys[name]=value
        print dict_keys
```

Comment: `getiterator` seems to have been deprecated since version 3.2. What would you recommend these days?